# Why is sulfate reduction less important in freshwater sediments?

Tags: geochemistry

Is this due to increased salinity reducing sulfate concentration or the production of marsh gas converting sulfate to hydrogen sulfide or something else?

Comment: What do you mean "less important". Hydrogen sulfide is bad in drinking water ( fresh ) and in oil well water ( salt/brine).